# Entity Framework code-first foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I am new to EF code first. When I tried to change cascade to "NoAction", Entity Framework just is creating another foreign key.

```
[Table("City")]
public partial class City
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<District> DistrictList { get; set; }
}

[Table("District")]
public partial class District
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CityId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("CityId")]
    public virtual City City { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<City>().HasMany(v => v.DistrictList).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

As a result, `District` table has `CityId` and `City_Id` at the same time.

Sorry for my bad English and thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using fluentapi and data annotations at same time. Just remove [ForeignKey] annotation from your City property if you are defining your relationship between entities in OnModelCreating method.

Answer (score 1):

You should use either ForeignKey-Attribute or ForeignKey-Property.

Additionally I´d try to use `WithOptional()` with type, like so: `WithOptional(e=>e.City)`. And if you want to define exactly what ef will create, you can use all configuration-possibilities:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<City>()
    .HasMany(v => v.DistrictList)
    .WithOptional(e=>e.City)
    .HasForeignKey(e=>e.CityId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```